# Julia - Readall blocks other tasks

Tags: asynchronous, connection, localhost, buffer, julia

I am currently looking a bit into the new language called Julia. I want to rewrite an oly python script from me and part of this script was to connect to a server, in that case that one from an android emulator.
But I have problem with the `read, readline, readall` function. When unsing these they do not really return and Julia waits and waits for getting more bytes. And on another project where the server does not send "\r\n" even `eof` waits forever. Is there a way that Julia just reads the bytes that were send by the server from a buffer, and does not wait for any? My current code for the connection looks like this:

```
client = connect("localhost", 7777)
@async while true
    if eof(client) == false
        line = readavailable(client)
        println(line)
    end
end
```

How can I code it, so that Julia runs the code when data arrives, but only reads what has arrived and nothing more and does not wait for any more data.
I also encounter a problem with `connect`. If I am using juli in terminal and want to make a connection to localhost on a port where nothing listen `client = connect("localhost", 7777)` I get an error message that the connection was refused but when using the same in a script the whole script also fails, but the whole script then stops, in other languages connect would return an error and I could try to handle the problem with my own code. Does anyone know why `connect()` crashes the whole script?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your question touches on 3 areas in julia.

1. **Non-Blocking I/O** - Ideally you could avoid `eof()` and `readavailable()` and combine non-blocking functions, for example:

```
    poll_fd(fd, time_s;readable=true)
    readbytes(fd, nb_available(fd))
```

But non-blocking I/O requires precise guarantees about atomic transitions and as far as I can see in 0.3.6, they aren't provided. So instead you can schedule a `close()`.

2. **Exception Handling** - Julia has `try/catch` to prevent an `Exception` from becoming fatal like in many other languages.
3. **C-Interfaces** - Many packages provide stubs to C libraries which may provide better functionality for specific protocols, I.e. HTTPClient with libcurl.

Example of integrating a workaround for (1) with the solution for (2):

```
println("start")
try 
    s = @spawn begin
        # client = connect("localhost", 7777)
        client = connect("yahoo.com", 80)
        write(client, "GET /\r\n\r\n") # comment this out to test waiting 
        @schedule (sleep(3.0); close(client))
        readall(client)
    end

    println(fetch(s))

catch exception
    println("No Luck:", exception)
end
println("done.")
```